# Apply CSS via JS with "if" statement

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I'm adding some iOS web app properties to my website and trying to create a `<div>` at the top of the page, with some CSS that is applied when a condition is met in a JS script.

However, it's not working and I'm not sure if I'm applying the styles correctly. I've demoed the same idea here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/679Qf/2/)

My actual script (on http://www.mtscollective.com) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function statusBarBG(){
    if (("standalone" in window.navigator) &amp;&amp; window.navigator.standalone) {
             $('.status-bar').css('width', '100%');
             $('.status-bar').css('height', '20px');
             $('.status-bar').css('position', 'fixed');
             $('.status-bar').css('background', '#454545');
             $('.status-bar').css('z-index', '9999');
               };
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have only defined function and not executing it simply you can do as self executing anonymous function as

```
(function statusBarBG(){
    if (("standalone" in window.navigator) &amp;&amp; window.navigator.standalone) {
             $('.status-bar').css('width', '100%');
             $('.status-bar').css('height', '20px');
             $('.status-bar').css('position', 'fixed');
             $('.status-bar').css('background', '#454545');
             $('.status-bar').css('z-index', '9999');
               };
    })();
```

also, in jsfiddle

1) you are not adding any jQuery library and not executing function

Updated jQuery woring **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/679Qf/3/)**

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand. Thanks! I've applied this to the site, but it's still not styling the div.

Comment: 1) check if there is any error in console 2) put alert("hi") in if and check whether code is executing 3) check jQuery library path is correct also it should be placed above statusBarBG code

Answer (score 0):

Try this method..

```
$('.status-bar').setAttribute("style","width: 100%");
$('.status-bar').setAttribute("style","height: 20px");
$('.status-bar').setAttribute("style","position: fixed");
$('.status-bar').setAttribute("style","background: #454545");
$('.status-bar').setAttribute("style","z-index: 9999");
```